# Firebase persistance - onDisconnect with multiple browser windows

Tags: javascript, firebase

We're writing an app that monitors online presence.  There are multiple scenarios where we need the user to have more than one browser window open.  We're running into a problem where the user, after opening and running the firebase js code in a secondary browser window, will close that secondary window.  This sets their presence to offline in the primary window because the onDisconnect event fires in the secondary window.

Is there a workaround for this scenario?  Is this where the special /.info/connected location could be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.info/connected` presence data only tells a given client if they are linked up to the Firebase server, so it won't help you in this case. You could try one of these:

**Reset the variable if it goes offline**

If you have multiple clients monitoring the same variable (multiple windows falls into this category), it's natural to expect them to conflict about presence values. Have each one monitor the variable for changes and correct it as necessary.

```
var ref = firebaseRef.child(MY_ID).child('status');
ref.onDisconnect().remove();
ref.on('value', function(ss) {
   if( ss.val() !== 'online' ) {
      // another window went offline, so mark me still online
      ss.ref().set('online');
   }
});
```

This is fast and easy to implement, but may be annoying since my status might flicker to offline and then back online for other clients. That could, of course, be solved by putting a short delay on any change event before it triggers a UI update.

**Give each connection its own path**

Since the purpose of the `onDisconnect` is to tell you if a particular client goes offline, then we should naturally give each client its own connection:

```
var ref = firebaseRef.child(MY_ID).child('status').push(1);
ref.onDisconnect().remove();
```

With this use case, each client that connects adds a new child under `status`. If the path is not null, then there is at least one client connected.

It's actually fairly simple to check for online presence by just looking for a truthy value at `status`:

```
firebaseRef.child(USER_ID).child('status').on('value', function(ss) {
    var isOnline = ss.val() !== null;
});
```

A downside of this is that you really only have a thruthy value for `status` (you can't set it to something like "idle" vs "online"), although this too could be worked around with just a little ingenuity.

**Transactions don't work in this case**

My first thought was to try a transaction, so you could increment/decrement a counter when each window is opened/closed, but there doesn't seem to be a `transaction` method off the `onDisconnect` event. So that's how I came up with the multi-path presence value.

Comment: thnx @Kato!  I went with solution #1:  Reset the variable if it goes offline.  Works like a charm.  The minor flicker when the user closes the secondary browser is no biggie to us.

Comment: There is an edge case. When you register a new user whilst still logged in, auth state changes -> the previous user should be offline but the onDisconnect() doesnt fire so there is a ghost user.

Comment: To avoid this you have to make sure that you logoff AND disconnect from firebase before logging in/registering (check the `goOffline` and `signOut` methods).

Comment: Sorry guys, wrong advice. Just make sure to remove the presence ref  (not the single array element but the the entire array) before logging in

Comment: Is it possible to get a complete example of the solutions presented herein?  Or is there a better solution now?

Comment: Does anyone know how to set 'away' with the first method?

Comment: For away, use onDisconnect().set() instead of remove(). Or logically in your code, when it's removed, mark them away.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution (Using angularfire2, but using pure firebase is similar):

```
const objRef = this.af.database.list('/users/' + user_id);
const elRef = objRef.push(1);
elRef.onDisconnect().remove();
```

Each time a new tab is opened a new element is added to the array. The reference for "onDisconnect" is with the new element, and only it is excluded.

The user will be offline when this array is empty.

Comment: This is genius!